# Angularjs only triggering ng-change on input radio the first time its selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have made a simple example using angularjs. This example contains three radio inputs, each of which have to call a function on change (ng-change => console.log). Unfortunately, the function its only triggered the first time any radio input is selected.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="radioGroupController">
    <div ng-repeat="value in values">{{value}}
        <input type="radio" name="name" ng-model="val" value="{{value}}" ng-change="logChange(val)" />
        <hr/>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('radioGroupController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.values = ['Option1', 'Option2', 'Option3'];
    $scope.logChange = function (newValue) {
        console.log('Changed to ' + newValue);
    };
}]);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected beheaviour?

**EDIT:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergioFC/ef5L5fdg/1/)

Comment: Works fine for me... However it is better to use `ng-value="value"` instead of `value="{{value}}"` http://plnkr.co/edit/tMW2yT?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couple of issues/changes:-

1- Change `value={{value}}` to [`ng-value="value"`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) because ng-value - Binds the given expression to the value of input[select] or input[radio], so that when the element is selected, the ngModel of that element is set to the bound value.

2- You need to set the selected value on the property on parent scope, you have ng-repeat and you really are setting value of the child scope, so each radio has its own child scope and its value never changes so ng-change is not triggered.

3- You do not need to pass the model value though `logChange` scope will already have it.

Try:-

In your controller add:-

```
  $scope.selected = {};
```

and view set the model as a property on `selected` property of controller scope instead of ng-repeated child scope's `val` property:-

```
 <input type="radio" name="name" ng-model="selected.val"
                  ng-value="value" ng-change="logChange()" />
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tMW2yT?p=preview)**

Answer (score 3):

You can change `ng-change` to `ng-click`, then it fires every time you actually click on the button.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/7004/).

Depending on what you want to achieve, consider [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) or [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) for your purpose.

> If you bind ng-model to "values" or whatever, you can check which
>   value it has and work with that. [Angulars advantage is exactly this
>   two-way-databinding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding) without doing anything. No need to call a
>   function to pass an argument.

Comment: Thanks, +1 because ng-click its a good idea for this example case and $watch its always useful to watch for variable changes.